# Already read Motzeh Others

Tags: purim, megillat-esther, halacha

If a Baal Koreh already read can he Be motzeh Other men?

Comment: Read what? Torah? Zachor? Haftarah?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes per Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 692-3, Mogain Avraham 585-3.